# How can I deserialize empty XML elements to null instead of empty strings using the Symfony serializer?

Tags: php, xml, symfony, deserialization

I am working on a Symfony application. This application uses the [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html) to deserialize XML objects. These XML objects contain [(self-closing) empty elements](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp).

Let's define a minimal model of the object in PHP:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Model;

class PhpObject
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $required;

    /**
     * @var null|string
     */
    private $optional;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRequired(): string
    {
        return $this->required;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $required
     */
    public function setRequired(string $required): void
    {
        $this->required = $required;
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getOptional(): ?string
    {
        return $this->optional;
    }

    /**
     * @param string|null $optional
     */
    public function setOptional(?string $optional): void
    {
        $this->optional = $optional;
    }
}
```

I autowired the serializer using the constructor and then deserialize some XML:

```php
    $xml = '
        <phpobject>
            <required>foo</required>
            <optional/>
        </phpobject>
    ';

    $result = $this->serializer->deserialize(
         $xml,
         PhpObject::class,
         XmlEncoder::FORMAT,
    );
```

The resulting object `$result` has now two values:

- `required` = "foo"
- `optional` = ""

How can I achieve that the `optional` value is `null` instead of ""?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know the best practice for it, but you can try this.

Change `setOptional` function to this

```
     /**
     * @param string|null $optional
     */
    public function setOptional(?string $optional): void
    {
        $this->optional = $optional === '' ? null : $optional;
    }
```